# How can you test functions and variables within your react component's render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to improve my test coverage for my react components, but I am having trouble testing variables and functions declared within the render method of my components. Below are a couple of examples that I'm unable to get covered:

1)

```
cityStateZip = `${cityStateZip} - ${location.zipExtension}`;
```

2)

```
directionsUrl = `maps://maps.apple.com/?saddr=My+Location&daddr=${gpsCoords.lat}+${gpsCoords.lng}`;
```

3)

```
const onClick = (pricingTileId) => {
  if (store.selectedPharmacy !== pricingTileId) {
    store.setPharmacy(pricingTileId);
  }
};
```

Here's the code:

```
class Tile extends Component {
  const { location, store } = this.props;
  render() {
    let directionsUrl = `https://maps.google.com/?saddr=My+Location&daddr=${gpsCoords.lat}+${gpsCoords.lng}`;
    if (navigator.platform.indexOf('iPhone') !== -1
      || navigator.platform.indexOf('iPod') !== -1
      || navigator.platform.indexOf('iPad') !== -1) {
      directionsUrl = `maps://maps.apple.com/?saddr=My+Location&daddr=${gpsCoords.lat}+${gpsCoords.lng}`;
    }

    let cityStateZip = `${location.city}, ${location.state} ${location.zip}`;
    if (location.zipExtension) {
      cityStateZip = `${cityStateZip} - ${location.zipExtension}`;
    }

    const onClick = (pricingTileId) => {
      if (store.selectedLocation !== pricingTileId) {
        store.setLocation(pricingTileId);
      }
    };

    let selectedClass;
    if (store.selectedLocation === id) {
      selectedClass = 'selected';
    }

    return (

    )
```

Is there an effective way to test the variables and functions declared in the render function that I'm overlooking? (I'm using Jest and Enzyme for my testing). Thank you!

Comment: as a general rule, it's hard to test logic _within_ a large function that's doing a lot of things. That's why it's recommended to write several smaller methods which the render function can then use; let `getCityStateZip()` handle the zip extension logic and `getDirectionsUrl()` handle the device-specific logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refactor your component like this:

```
class Tile extends Component {

  isMobile = () => {
    let mob = navigator.platform

    if (mob.indexOf('Iphone')) return true
    if (mob.indexOf('Ipad')) return true
    if (mob.indexOf('Ipod')) return true

    return false
  }

  isZipValid = () => !!this.props.location.zipExtension
  isLocationValid = (id) => this.props.store.location === id


  handleClick = (pricingTileId) => {
    const { store } = this.props;

    if (store.selectedLocation !== pricingTileId) {
      store.setLocation(pricingTileId);
    }
  }

  render() {


    let directionsUrl
    let selectedClass = isLocationValid() && 'selected';
    let cityStateZip = `${location.city}, ${location.state} ${location.zip}`;

    if (!isMobile()) {
      directionsUrl = `maps://maps.apple.com/?saddr=My+Location&daddr=${gpsCoords.lat}+${gpsCoords.lng}`;
    }

    if (isZipValid()) {
      cityStateZip = `${cityStateZip} - ${location.zipExtension}`;
    }
    return (
      <div> Anything</div>
    )
  }
```

..

============== PART 2 ==================

You can extract them to a separate file such as `lib` or `helpers`
and then import it to your components.

Like this:

Helper:

//helpers.js

```
export const isMobile = (mob) => {

    if (mob.indexOf('Iphone')) return true
    if (mob.indexOf('Ipad')) return true
    if (mob.indexOf('Ipod')) return true

    return false
  }
```

Finally on the component:

```
   export { isMobile } from './helpers'

   if(isMobile(navigator.platform)){

    //you just abstracted the function

   }
```

**Conclusion: your `isMobile()` can be easily tested from the helpers and supply to any component :)**

**Now you can easily test function by function**

I hope it helped you :D

Kindly,

Comment: Makes sense, thank you! This might be a foolish question, but I'm very new to testing of this nature. How do I access these methods in my test? The isMobile function for example. I'm importing and console logging my Tile component, but can't seem to locate these methods anywhere. Not quite sure how to test them. Thanks very much for the assistance :)

Comment: check part two on my post above